# MongoDB aggregate lookup not working for localfield _id

Tags: mongodb, lookup, aggregation, mongoose-schema

Here is my content `Schema` -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const ContentSchema = new Schema({
    linkName: {
        type: String,

    },
    noteUrl: {
        type: String,
    },
    url: {
        type: String,
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Content', ContentSchema);
```

And content comment `Schema` -

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;
const contentCommentSchema = new Schema({
    text: {
        type: String,

    },
    user: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    content: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Content'
    }
},
{
    timestamps: true

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('contentComment', contentCommentSchema);
```

When I am trying to `$lookup` from contentComment it returns 0 records every time. But in db comments are created for corresponding content. Here is the `Aggregation` -

```
const contentPromise = Content.aggregate([
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: "contentComments",
            localField: "_id",
            foreignField: "content",
            as: "comments"
        }
    }]);
```

Am I missing anything there?

Comment: Are you using `await` to ensure query has ended to see the data?

Comment: Yes, I am using `Promise` there

Comment: Your model is called `contentComment` but in your query you are using collection `contentCommentS` I think

Comment: Mongoose automagically create the relative table with the plural mode.

Comment: make sure you have object id type in `content` field in actual collection, i can see correct in your schema.